# Why invoke an inline function immediately, rather than just calling its contained function?

Tags: go, closures

When assigning value to a struct field.

```
    FlagSet: (func() *flag.FlagSet {
        fs := newFlagSet("configure")
        return fs
    })(),
```

I think it's equivelent to just calling newFlagSet("configure").What's the benefit writing like this.

question when reading source.Need to know why he write like this.

Comment: I think you're right. It would be equivalent, and simpler.  My guess: The inline function was necessary in the past, or in other parts of the code, and was not refactored when it became no longer necessary or when it was copy/pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a [quick search](https://github.com/search?q=%22flag.FlagSet%22+newFlagSet%28%22configure%22%29+language%3AGo&type=code), this code comes from [`tailscale/tailscale`, `cmd/tailscale/cli/configure.go#var configureCmd = &ffcli.Command{}`](https://github.com/tailscale/tailscale/blob/65dc711c7645a5d7de7f6b2a748fa9e4d0e5f080/cmd/tailscale/cli/configure.go#L23-L26)

```golang
var configureCmd = &ffcli.Command{
    Name:      "configure",
    ShortHelp: "[ALPHA] Configure the host to enable more Tailscale features",
    LongHelp: strings.TrimSpace(`
The 'configure' set of commands are intended to provide a way to enable different
services on the host to use Tailscale in more ways.
`),
    FlagSet: (func() *flag.FlagSet {
        fs := newFlagSet("configure")
        return fs
    })(),
    Subcommands: configureSubcommands(),
    Exec: func(ctx context.Context, args []string) error {
        return flag.ErrHelp
    },
}
```

That code uses a [function literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Function_literals) (anonymous function), which is then immediately invoked.

That is known as an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://golangbyexample.com/immediately-invoked-function-go/). This is more common in languages like JavaScript, but can be useful in Go as well.

In Go, IIFE allows you to isolate a piece of logic that produces a value, creating a scoped environment for variables that will not pollute the surrounding namespace.
The variables used within the anonymous function (`fs` in this case) do not escape into the surrounding code. This makes the code easier to reason about, as the variables live only as long as they are needed.

While it is true `FlagSet: newFlagSet("configure"),` is equivalent to `FlagSet: (func() *flag.FlagSet { fs := newFlagSet("configure"); return fs})()`, some advantages of the second form could be:

- Extensibility: Should future modifications of `newFlagSet("configure")` require more complex operations or computations, these changes can be easily incorporated within the anonymous function without altering the structure of `configureCmd`.
- Debugging: The encapsulated logic can be easily commented out, logged, or modified during debugging sessions without disturbing the surrounding code.

Looking at [tailscale code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Atailscale%2Ftailscale+newFlagSet&type=code) though, that particular IIFE usage seems limited to that one instance.

Comment: interesting, the explanation is compelling. I'm not fully convinced that it's warranted at all times though. It seems a significant tradeoff in readability for a very minor advantage in variable scoping. Also the use-case from golangbyexample is a really poor one because the IIFE doesn't declare any intermediate var, that code should just be `squareOf2 := 2*2`

Comment: @blackgreen I agree. This is to be used with moderation ;)